# Zipkin Brave v4 - Propagating spans from request to

Tags: zipkin

Springboot app.

I'm using Brave v4 and trying not to use the brave-core module for when it is deprecated in the future. With Brave v3 it was easy to pass around the current span as it was kept within the thread and handled by the Brave class.

I'm using the async-http-client client and I've created request and response filters which propagate to and from the header as well as starting and submitting spans. This all works as expected.
The async-http-client pool is wired up at startup with the listeners attached, the listeners receive a TracingImpl which is just a wrapper for the Tracer class so that the listeners can do the submitting etc (well the spans inside can start/finish themselves)

My problem is for example: a request comes into the controller, I extract the Span from the request and now I want to use the async-http-client to make another request which would be a child of the one coming in.
I'm unsure how I should get the Span object I now have in my controller to the async-http-client object to it.
Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I should have added, the async-http-client request could be a couple of levels deep and would prefer not to pass a span object through the layers.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there's no replacement for the "thread binder" apis. There will be in the coming months. This is indeed needed to renovate existing instrumentation.

Until then, you can re-use thread binders via TracerAdapter or use a different in-process propagation library. The following link includes a working example https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/brave#upgrading-from-brave-3